# Template layout of Sign-In form from Material-UI is messed up

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I try getting familiar with the concept of Material-UI by downloading the source code of the template, e.g. Sign In, and run it on my localhost

Source code: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/pages/getting-started/templates/sign-in/SignIn.js

However, the layout is messed up and not as I expect

[image]

I have read the documentation about Text Field, https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/, but it does not help.

Could you guy help me please?

Comment: I have checked in codesandbox, it works. Something wrong in your environment..

Comment: You are right! It is because of my local CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

Material-UI is a react library so you have to React and also Node installed on your machine. You can't just download and run it.

You can follow this video to see how React and Material-UI are installed.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zT62eVxShsY&t=1480s

Just make sure to download Node before you do that.

https://nodejs.org/en/